# Import Pre-formatted text to Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to import the entire text in the below URL to the Google Sheets. the URL has pre-formatted text. I tried `importHTML` and `importXML`, but to no avail. please anyone help me to find out the correct way.

[Link](http://portal.amfiindia.com/DownloadNAVHistoryReport_Po.aspx?mf=3&tp=1&frmdt=01-Jan-2004&todt=30-Sep-2019)

Comment: Have you considered using `fetch()`? You can take a look at [its documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  Yes I have tried fetch(). The whole content is copied to single cell. I have no idea how to copy the imported content to sheet.please help

Comment: You're trying to separate it by line, correct? I tried to do it with `fetch`, using `split("\n")` to separate them by line, but there is just too much data, it throws an error about how it would surpass the max number of cells allowed in a sheet. you'll need to find a better way to organize it.